# Linux command for switching user with password as parameter

Tags: shell-script, sudo, users

I want to write the Linux shell script that switches the user without asking for password, i.e. password can be specified as the parameter.

I have my script like this `startService.sh`

```
sudo su hduser -p mypassword
```

but this is not working.

Can anyone tell how to specify the password in the command itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `-S` switch which reads the password from standard input like this:

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S command
```

From [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> `-S` (stdin) option causes `sudo` to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

**But there's a catch.** It works for the current user only. I can't find a way around it, at least.